# How can I move my preexisting DA:O mods to a new Windows installation?

Tags: mods, dragon-age-origins

Recently I suffered a hardware failure that necessitated a clean install of Windows. I've been wanting to get back into the Dragon Age series so I can come into Inquisition freshly reminded of all the nuances of the game...but there's a minor problem.

My old install had a large number of quality-of-life improvements and bug fixes. It also had Dragon Age Redesigned, which as I recall is difficult to install. I know most of this content is installed in the user configuration folder under the local user Documents folder, but I'm unsure if any of my mods might have modified the main install. Since the fresh Steam install needs to verify the files first and will redownload if it finds anything amiss, I was thinking I could just install and then paste mods and the old install over it...but I'm also worried about configuration files being screwed up, and failing to recognize my DLC or something. Any particular procedures or pitfalls I should know about?

If it matters, I'm using a Steam copy! (And I've still got to move New Vegas, too...)